# How to overcome "No module named 'keras'" while importing tensoflow_hub

Tags: tensorflow, keras, installation, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am using Anaconda and Jupyter Notebook. I need a `tensorflow_hub` to import the ResNet model, however, I get the error `No module named Keras`. I've installed keras and tensorflow_hub in Anaconda. I have no issues when I am using keras.

Comment: Open a terminal -> activate the cond env -> next: `!pip install --upgrade tensorflow_hub`

Comment: It still doesn't  work :(((

Comment: after installing the tf_hub form terminal, also verify the installation there (not from notebook).

Comment: I've verified the installation in the terminal, but the problem doesn't disappear https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXRwz.png

Comment: Can you try wit pip. And after installing, try to import hub from the command line.

Comment: After importing from the command line, I've got this thing https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZReN.png

Answer (score 0):

This `"AlreadyExistsError: Another metric with the same name already exists."` error shows up when you have a mismatch version of `TensorFlow` and `Keras` installed in your system.

To verify this, please run below code in jupyter notebook:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)

import keras
print(keras.__version__)
```

You can resolve this error by upgrading the `TensorFlow` to the latest version as this error has been resolved in the latest `TF releases - 2.7, 2.8`:

```
!pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

and import `Keras` from `TensorFlow` like this:

```
from tensorflow import keras
```

Now you can install and import `tensorflow_hub` using the below code without any error:

```
!pip install tensorflow_hub
import tensorflow_hub
```